# What is the best detailed commentary in English on Shri Narada Purana?

Tags: puranas, narada, narada-purana

I research Motilal Banarsidass edition 1995 and struggle to find the origin of GauriPati Shatanama Stotra गौरीपतिशतनामस्तोत्रम्.

Please, help to locate a pdf or document that can be searched for the purpose of decent translation of the above-mentioned Stotra.